# jQuery bind inside a for loop variable scope

Tags: jquery, scope

I know this question has been asked many times but I haven't been able to resolve from what I found on Stack O. Here is my code

```
for(var i=0; i<retrievedSearchesListLength; i++){
retrievedSearchesListProv = retrievedSearchesList[i].searchId;
retrievedSearchesListType = retrievedSearchesList[i].searchParameters;

    function getEventHandlerFunction(a){
    $J.cookies.set('ps_clickedsearch',a);
}

 $J('#submitSearch'+i).bind('click',getEventHandlerFunction(retrievedSearchesListType));
}
```

---

Everytime the resulting value is the last for loop value. How do I keep scope so that the link clicked results in the correct value?

I need the correct retrievedSearchesListType to reflect when the link is clicked.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the callback method from `getEventHandlerFunction`

```
for(var i=0; i<retrievedSearchesListLength; i++){
    retrievedSearchesListProv = retrievedSearchesList[i].searchId;
    retrievedSearchesListType = retrievedSearchesList[i].searchParameters;

    function getEventHandlerFunction(a){
        return function(){
            $J.cookies.set('ps_clickedsearch',a);
        }
    }

    $J('#submitSearch'+i).bind('click',getEventHandlerFunction(retrievedSearchesListType));
}
```